# My Minecraft won't work at all how do I fix it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I click on my minecraft to start it, it doesn't go to any screen but a small box that says "The registry refers to a nonexistent Java Run-time Installation or the runtime is corrupted.

The system cannot find the file specified" Help?

Comment: Are you using mods?

Answer (score 2):

You might not have a JRE installed. It would really help if we could see a crash report or something. Try re-downloading java and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

***WARNING this will only work if you are in minecraft 10 snapshot I don t know about the later versions.***

When you open the launcher you should see something like this in the bottom left. Click the edit profile (the thing framed in red) anything else you see there doesn t matter.

When you click it another window should pop-up. Find the "Java settings (advanced)"[image]
When you manage to find this check "JVM Arguments" if they are not aleready checked. Change the first segment of the code (also framed in red) and change it so it will look like the picture. Change ***ONLY*** the stuff between the dashes.

I m not sure if you have got to have Java.

I am so sorry for my grammar and spelling.